# ClaimsPrincipal with custom UserManager doesn't work in razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

I've an asp.net project that contains controller and razor pages together.
Asp.net Identity creates own area with razor pages as default with scaffolding.

Problem starts after login, in controller, I can use `User` keyword to see current user's claims like, Id, username, email.. without problem. When I call the `User` keyword in Identity pages, it comes with 0 claims inside and `await userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` returns `null`

I'm using built-in Sign-in Manager.

Am I missing something?

Update:
Profile pages working with ClaimsPrincipal, when I click to Setup Authenticator App link, it is coming with 0 claims as in image below.
[image: User keyword expanded]

It was working before, once I added Authenticator app into my account and removed it then started this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when 2 factor authentication enabled and when you login with 2fa and check remember this browser and remove 2fa from your account.
Clearing 2FA cookies fixes the problem

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5817#issuecomment-491818987